# How to append data of all Parquet files from a folder of s3 bucket into a single dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, s3-bucket

In my folder there are around 10 parquet files with same column names.
I want to append all 10 parquet files data into one dataframe.
I used below code but dataframe is having only first files data.

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
complete_path="s3://s3bucket/folder_path
df=pq.ParquetDataset(complete_path,filesystem=s3).read_pandas().
           to_pandas()
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: First you need to get the list of files present in the bucket path, use boto3 s3 client pagination to list all the files or keys. Once you have the list of files that you need, just read them individually and push the df into a list, later concat them into a single df

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am so new to aws, can you please help with the code of how can I list all files using boto3

Comment: sure, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the above code which I have mentioned in question.

Comment: would recommend you look into these - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44376294/8872639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/24634232/8872639, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39201093/8872639